# How to fight flooding for a website?

Tags: web

I know,time restriction implementation as adopted on stackoverflow.com is a way to fight flooding. But sometimes I really want to input another message soon after I input a previous one and I want to wait until the time restriction is lifted. Is there other elegant way to fight flooding?

Answer (score 1):

You could augment the time-control restriction - rather than one submission every {time}, allow {somenumber} submissions every {longertime}.